# Rails API - Casting string parameters to enum values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

In a Ruby on Rails application, say there is a model with an `enum` field like:

```rb
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum color: {
    blue: 0,
    green: 1,
    red: 2
  }
end
```

There is an API endpoint exposed for creating new instances of my model.

The value being sent for `params[:color]` does not match up with the `enum` keys.
(e.g. something like 'Deep Ocean Blue' is being sent as the parameter value).

I know that I could change my `enum` to be something like:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum color: {
    'Deep Ocean Blue' => 0,
    # ... etc.
  }
end
```

but then this makes the Rails generated methods for the `enum` strange and hard to use...

```rb
my_car.blue?
my_car.send('Deep Ocean Blue?') # not even sure this works but you get the idea
```

My question is, what is the best ("Railsiest") way to handle a situation like this?

Should I be creating a mapping of parameters and enum keys, and cast the correct enum value in a before_validation hook, or is there a better way of handling this?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `deep_blue_ocean` and if you need the display it then `to_s.humanize` should fix that and converting back can be handled by `underscore`. You could even use `alias_method :blue?, :deep_blue_ocean?` if your code is already littered with these calls or if you only have 1 blue.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `underscore` method if you have constant color options

```
2.6.5 :007 > "Deep Ocean Blue".parameterize.underscore
=> "deep_ocean_blue"
```

You may keep the enum as

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum color: {
    'deep_ocean_blue' => 0,
    'golden_rose' => 1,
    # ... etc.
  }
end
```

Any while creating the object convert the parameter color to `underscore`

```
Car.create(color: params[:color].parameterize.underscore, # other parameters ..)
```